# HTML - Break Line While Getting Input From TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

My Problem Is,

When I Type Multi Lines In TextArea I Get Output Like This,

[upper one is input and lower one is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8UKC.jpg)

But I Want To Get Output Like This,

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4E2C.jpg)

In This Photo I Used `<br/>` Just For Making The Look What I Want But, In Real I Don't Want To Use `<br/>` To Break Line In Multi Line

**This Is Th Code I'm Using...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <TextArea id = "Input" onKeyupUp = "showResult()" style = "height: 100px; width: 100%; resize: none;"> </TextArea>
  <Div id = "output" ></Div>
</body>

<script>
  function showResult(){
    var input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
      document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = input;
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textarea uses newline in text format like `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`. So, simple regex to convert anyof these to HTML newline: `<br />` will solve your issue.

```
var inputHTML = input.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />");
```

```js
function showResult() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
  var inputHTML = input.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />");
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = inputHTML;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <TextArea id="Input" onKeyupUp="showResult()" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; resize: none;"></TextArea>
  <Div id="output"></Div>
  <button onclick="showResult()">SHOW</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Dude... You Rocked! :D

Answer (score -1):

Try PHP function nl2br() for your output

Comment: no `php` tag in OP. The server might not even be in php. There are simpler solutions with just client-side js as in tags.